# Using SQL to concatenate conditionally by time difference

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

Let's say I have a table like this:

```
unitID  unitName unitGroupName  unitDate   unitStartTime   unitEndTime
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
1       unitA    groupA         1/1/2019   9:00pm          11:00pm
1       unitA    groupB         1/1/2019   11:10pm         11:45pm
1       unitA    groupC         1/1/2019   11:55pm         1:20am
```

Is there a way to concatenate the rows conditionally?

The conditions would be as follows:

- unitIDs must all be the same
- unitDates must all be the same
- The unit times must be withing 20 minutes of each other --> *meaning, if groupA ends at 11:00pm and groupB starts at 11:10pm, then concatenation would occur.*

So given the above rules and the sample table & data above, the concatenation would look like this:

```
Name                    Date            startTime     endTime
-------------------------------------------------------------
groupA;groupB;groupC    1/1/2019        9:00pm        1:20am
```

Is something like this possible with SQL?

Here is the query I'm using based on the answer by @Tigerjz32

```
DECLARE @value VARCHAR(max) = NULL
SELECT @value = COALESCE(@value + ';' + ug.unitGroupName, ug.unitGroupName)
SELECT @value as Name, 
       MIN(ue.unitDate) as unitDate, 
       MIN(ue.unitStartTime) as unitStartTime, 
       MIN(ue.unitEndTime)as unitEndTime,
       u.unitName
FROM unitEvents ue
LEFT JOIN unitGroups ug ON ug.unitID = ue.unitID
LEFT JOIN units u ON ug.unitID = u.unitID
WHERE u.unitYear = 2018
AND ue.eventWeek between '12/1/2018' and '12/7/2018'
```

Thanks!

Comment: **Typo** alert - it's **concatenate** - not "contatenate" .....

Answer (score 1):

Here is a dirty way to do this. If you want to be more elegant, you should look into [pivoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017).

```
DECLARE @value VARCHAR(max) = NULL

SELECT @value = COALESCE(@value + ';' + ug.unitGroupName, ug.unitGroupName)
FROM unitGroups ug    

SELECT @value as Name, 
       MIN(ue.unitDate) as unitDate, 
       MIN(ue.unitStartTime) as unitStartTime, 
       MIN(ue.unitEndTime)as unitEndTime
FROM unitEvents ue
LEFT JOIN unitGroups ug ON ug.unitID = ue.unitID
LEFT JOIN units u ON ug.unitID = u.unitID
WHERE u.unitYear = 2018
AND ue.eventWeek between '12/1/2018' and '12/7/2018'
```

Comment: I tried that, and it produces the following error: The multi-part identifier "u.unitName" could not be bound. I added the query to the question above.  Thanks!

Comment: Try this solution please